# Different Recursion Output under different systems

Tags: c++, recursion

Consider the following c++ code for a simple binary tree DFS traversal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int print_vector(vector<char> *vec){
    for (auto &it: *vec)
        cout<<it;
    cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}

int btree_dfs_traversal(int max_depth, int cur_depth, vector<char> position){
    if (cur_depth>max_depth)
        return 0;
    print_vector(&position);
    vector<char>left = position;
    vector<char>right = position;
    left.push_back('l');
    right.push_back('r');
    return btree_dfs_traversal(max_depth, cur_depth+1, left)+btree_dfs_traversal(max_depth, cur_depth+1, right);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<char> pos;
    btree_dfs_traversal(4, 0, pos);
    return 0;
}
```

The function(a minimal example) visits a binary tree, and prints the "position" of each node it visits. The only difference with a standard DFS is that (this part made the difference), most implementation uses a **iteration** for visiting the two nodes, while my the `return` statement returns the **sum** of two visits.

I expected the program to recurse from the left statement, i.e. the output starts with `l`, `ll`, `lll`, ... And indeed in my system(OSX) it is like this, and [ideone](http://ideone.com/hEaJnE) has this output too.

However, in some friends' system, the output is different. The recursion starts from the **right** statement, i.e. `r`, `rr`... Unfortunately, I do not have exact information of their complier information at present.

My question is: is the **sum** of two recursion being a undefined behavior such that different compiler can produce different results? Or, it is just wrong to start from right?

Comment: It's not specified which of the two sides of an arithmetic expression will be evaluated first. You might want to read more about [evaluation order and sequencing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: The *sum* should be the same, but there's nothing in your program that displays it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, the usage of sum should be avoided in this case

Comment: @happyfish No, but you could store the result of the recursive calls in local variables to govern which call is executed first, and add the values afterwards.

Comment: @happyfish If you want a specified and fixed order for your calls, then you should make that order explicit. For example by doing `int a = btree_dfs_traversal(...); int b = btree_dfs_traversal(...); return a + b;`.

Comment: Also since you abort the recursion by returning 0 you only ever building the sum of zeroes. The result is always 0. If it weren't for the side effect of outputing l and r the code would be pointless. Did you mean to return 1 instead to get a count of nodes visited?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, I did that to fix the problem. thanks

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow this is just an over-simplified version of the original problem(the original problem has similar recursion structure but not really a tree traversal) that can demonstrate the error. the original problem does use the sum (and it is something else). now I know the cause of this strange behavior

Comment: BTW, a B-tree is a data structure that's related to but distinct from a binary tree.  Prefixing names with `btree_` could be confusing to readers of your code.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thanks, I didn't know there is such a data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that in `f(1) + f(2)` it is unspecified which function call comes first. Different compilers will pick different order and the order can depend on any number of unrelated factors. From the C++ reference:

**Order of evaluation**

Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.
There are exceptions to this rule which are noted below.

Except where noted below, there is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to f3 may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order for exceptions and more info.